# For custom buttons in Android Studio do I have to insert code in MainActivity.java?

Tags: java, android, android-button

I found a tutorial on YouTube which shows me how to make custom buttons, but something confuses me when I see with 3 images. It has 2 buttons while just the last one has its code in MainActivity.java
and the rest have code only in .xml files.

Code:

[image: code]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

pressed focus and normal
In the last part of the video he makes the normal image being a button and showing a text when clicked, and I don't know if both buttons work the same.

Can I change activity from the first kind of button which has no code in MainActivity.java?

Answer (score 0):

the 3 types that are defined are for different events of the button triggering like if the button is pressed or button is focused or button is long pressed or not.

for more information use this [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button#CustomBackground)

Comment: yes 3 states but this guy made from these 3 states 2 in a button (focused and pressed) and another one with (normal) and just for the normal one did the code in .JAVA file so I wonder if I need to put a click listener as he did in .Java I need just 1 button with all states and he made 2 I don't know the reason

Comment: first of all, a view is a view.whether its a button or a text view or any kind of visual element. you can put click listeners in any of the views that you can see in your screen.

Comment: and second if you want something to happen when the button is clicked you put that code inside the button click listner.

Comment: I wanna have a button with all that 3 states and give it a command to change activity buuut i'm not so good at programing that's why I watch and talk about this tutorial and try to understand it.He use all 3 states but creates 2 different buttons one is normal and the other one is focused and pressed and I don't want that I want all 3 in 1 single button which later I will make it to give another activity(I will change the layout/the page)

Comment: the file that the guy is writing is button.xml and you have to link the file into that button so use the property called android: background="@drawable/button.xml"